# how can I find the owner of a facebook app ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A while back I created an app ID on facebook and added the appropriate meta data to a website.  I now want to continue adding facebook-related features to the site, but it seems the app is not related to my account afterall.

I must have created it under a different account or something, but how can I find who the owner is based on an App ID?  I have existing likes, so I don't really want to change the App ID.  I don't see any way in the UI, and I do not see the app when I go to the Developer app.  Is there a way to do it using the Graph API?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**EDIT (Jan 2013)**

Looks like Facebook have removed app profile pages so that method no longer works.

---

**Option 1**
You could return the app object, which stores all the populated information about the app by requesting:

https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

**Option 2** *(This method no longer works)*
Or, you could visit the app's profile page and contact the developer directly using the 'contact developer' link:

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

*(you'll need to replace xxxxxxxxxxx with your app id)*

Comment: I have actually tried both already.  The object only contains the name, some images, and the app page link.  Contacting the developer did not send an email to me.

Comment: Well, turns out it sent an email to my wife, so sorted :)

Comment: I don't seem to get a 'contact developer' link for an app whose developer I'm searching for.  It says "You are being redirected to the xxxxxx web app." and doesn't provide any more info.

Comment: Having the same issue except my app isn't appearing in the app store as it's "misconfigured". Awesome! Anyone have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: This isn't working at all for me, I get an "Unsupported get request" response.

Comment: Didn't try the first solution, but it seems others have. However the second one just redirects to facebook.com/ Are there any new ways to find or contact the developer behind an app id?

Comment: @miyalys The second solution no longer works, FB removed app profile pages (see edit Jan 2013)

Answer (score 91):

If you have access to the `app id` and the `app secret` but no access to the app within Facebook it is possible to discover the creator_uid and from there the email address of the app owner using the graph api.

First get an app access token:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials`

With this you can get the creator_uid:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}?access_token={APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}&fields=creator_uid`

Using the app token you will then get the email address when looking up the `creator_uid` in the graph api:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{creator_uid}?access_token={APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}`

Comment: yeh, this is the best answer IMO. thanks so much! you saved me much hair pulling over an old legacy bit of code.

Comment: Can't get email address using this solution. I forgot the email address to the main account

Comment: Yes, Facebook has now changed the way this works and it looks like you can't get the email address this way any longer.

Answer (score 6):

I got this working. If you have both app id and app secret then you can try below steps to get the owner details.

1. Get the access token using id and secret of the facebook app.

   [https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%7BAPP_ID%7D&client_secret=%7BAPP_SECRET%7D&grant_type=client_credentials)
2. Using the access token you can call the below API to get a list of administrators of the app.

   [https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}?fields=id,name,roles&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BAPP_ID%7D?fields=id,name,roles&access_token=%7BACCESS_TOKEN%7D)
3. Retrieve the owner profile details by,

   [https://www.facebook.com/{USER_ID}](https://www.facebook.com/%7BUSER_ID%7D)

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem, in that I have the **id** and the **secret** but no access to the app within facebook.

I haven't found a way to see who owns does have access to the app. But I have found a way to contact a dev

First get the app access token. 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials

Then get the address:
https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}?access_token={APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}

Comment: this doesn't give me any more information than not supplying the app access token

Comment: see my answer for the complete picture on how to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30595303/1062129