# Given a Facebook App ID is there a way to identify or contact the developer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm a codeveloper on a website which has a Facebook like button, and for this an App ID has been created at some point in the past and added to the meta headers.

The problem is we are not sure who created that App ID in the past, so that we can change the app's settings etc. A solution would simply be to make a new app for the site, but I'm curious if that's really necessary? I found an [old Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338996/how-can-i-find-the-owner-of-a-facebook-app-id) on the topic, however those solutions no longer seem to be working, and AFAICS we only use the App ID of the site at the moment, not any secret key or access token. (That is we don't know what those are, if they have been created.)

Comment: I found out how to do it using the graph api if you have the app id and the app secret. Posted a new answer on the old question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this is not possible, because the relevant fields are not public:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app

For example, a query on the Graph Explorer like this

```
GET /145634995501895?fields=id,name,creator_uid,contact_email
```

only returns this

```
{
  "id": "145634995501895", 
  "name": "Graph API Explorer"
}
```

So, I think you probably need to create a new app.